# Create tuple from Django Raw Query Set

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a simple query:

```
q = `Select * from table`
Table.objects.raw(q)
```

which will give me `RawQuerySet`.

Is there a way to get the result in the form of tuple of tuples ?
eg If there would have been just 2 fields in the table, then the result would look like:

```
((1, 'name1'), (2, name2))
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing a raw SQL query instead of using the ORM? `Table.objects.all()`?

Comment: Actually query is somewhat complicated with 4 JOINS and 1 UNION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to return model instances, then I don't see any advantage in using `raw()`. You can [execute custom SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) directly instead:

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s', [self.baz])
    result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3):

Any reason not to do it in Python?

```
rqs = Table.objects.raw(q)
tuples = tuple((o.pk, o.name) for o in rqs)
```

Comment: I dont know the names of the fields beforehand